# SSIS in Azure: Execution Reports are Blank

Tags: ssis, report

We are running SSIS packages in AZure and when I click on the "All Messages" or "Overview" link in the All Executions report list those reports are empty. When I went to the SSISDB database and looked in the internal.operations table it has the data that is in the All Execution list, but the internal.event_messages_scaleout table is empty for operation after 5/3/22. It does not matter if the execution failed or succeeded, there is not data in the internal.event_messages_scaleout table.
Also should note that when the job succeeds, the logging that I have built into the package works and tells me what has happened (point is the package works, but something is stopping the standard SSIS logging from recording).
Not sure what to look for to get the data to start writing back into that table.
[image: All Executions]

[image: Messages for Operation Id:396]